# GroovyTemplates properties configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to configure the properties of GroovyTemplates. I checked the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) document, but formatting options are not available through the *application.properties* file. So I did the following to customize some other properties.

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration.GroovyMarkupConfiguration configuration;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        this.configuration.groovyTemplateConfiguration().setUseDoubleQuotes(true);
        this.configuration.groovyTemplateConfiguration().setAutoNewLine(true);
        this.configuration.groovyTemplateConfiguration().setAutoIndent(true);

    }
}
```

I can see the double quotes in the rendered HTML files. However, it is still unformatted.

So, I have two questions. The first one is, how can I set the properties properly? Most probably, the one I did is not the proper way. The second question is, why do I still get the unformatted HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs it says

```
spring.groovy.template.configuration.*= # See Groovy's TemplateConfiguration
```

So I assume that corresponds up the properties you set (what you are doing isn't wrong, necessarily, but it might happen too late to influence the behaviour at runtime). I would stick with the `application.properties` if I were you.

Comment: But you can not change those in the application.properties file.

Comment: It looks to me very much like you can. Are you saying you tried it and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes you are right. It's working now. I didn't pay attention the configuration keyword. Thanks.